# Как заполнить дополнить данные пустыми значениями (postgres)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть запрос, который достает данные по статистике за определенный период времени.

`SELECT product_count, created_at::date FROM statistic WHERE created_at::date >= '2015-05-05' AND created_at::date <= '2015-05-08' GROUP BY created_at::date`

Если у меня есть данные только по 2м датам, к примеру для 2015-05-05 и 2015-05-06 а для остальных дат данных нет.
На выходе я получу

```
product_count | created_at
--------------+------------
1             | 2015-05-05
3             | 2015-05-06
```

Мне нужно до заполнить нулями остальные данные, что бы получить на выходе типа:

```
product_count | created_at
--------------+-------------
1             | 2015-05-05
3             | 2015-05-06
2             | 2015-05-07
5             | 2015-05-08
```

Как такой запрос сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте такой запрос: `SELECT COALESCE(product_count, 0), created_at::date FROM statistic WHERE created_at::date >= '2015-05-05' AND created_at::date <= '2015-05-08' GROUP BY created_at::date`.

Comment: Проблема не в значении по умолчании, а в получении всех дней даже если данных для этих дней нет в БД

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Группировка не вернёт данных, которых и нет. Но можно сгенерировать непрерывный набор дат с помощью функции generate_series и приджойнить к нему выборку с группировкой:

```
select created_date, coalesce(product_count, 0) as product_count -- но, возможно, null вам и удобнее будет
from generate_series('2015-05-05', '2015-05-08', '1 day') as created_date
    left join (
        SELECT sum(product_count) as product_count, 
            created_at::date as created_date 
        FROM statistic 
        WHERE created_at >= '2015-05-05' 
            AND created_at < ('2015-05-08' + interval '1 day') 
        GROUP BY created_date
    ) groupdata using (created_date)
```

Обратите внимание, я изменил ваше условие `created_at::date >= '2015-05-05'`. Ваш запрос не может использовать индекс по `created_at`, а только функциональный по `created_at::date`. Если у вас уже есть этот функциональный индекс, то эта замена не нужна - просто заострю внимание других читающих.